# Google Sheets & GAS: Can't access a GAS project that I own directly from Tools -> Script editor, only by search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

**The scenario:**

1. I make a copy of a spreadsheet that has a bounded script.
2. On the new copy, I go to "Tools -> Script editor".
3. I get this error:

[image: I get this error]

4. When I go to https://script.google.com/ and search for the project - I find it and can access & edit it.

**Notes**

a. This is a new user.

b. From a different user that has editor permissions - the same process allows opening the script via the "Tools -> Script editor".

c. Both users has the same permissions (editor) to the Google Drive folder where the copy is placed.

d. Both are organizational users.

e. This also happens for the user experiencing issues in case the ownership of a spreadsheet with bounded spript is granted to the user.

**How can I solve this behavior?**

Thank you,

Comment: Signed in with multiple gmail user account in one chrome environment ?

Comment: Yes, doing it from incognuito solved the problem! Thanks, I did not think to check that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

*Multiple accounts are not supported in Apps Script. Use one single account or incognito mode*